# Returning automatic derivatives with Sympy

Tags: python, automation, sympy, derivative

I'm trying to build a class whose goal is returning the derivative of a function `f` also as a function. I've read about Sympy and I started to try it with this package.

#### Main problem

Let's suppose that I have a simple function with only one parameter, like this:

```
def f1p(x):
    return x**2 + 5**x * 2*x + 1
```

Now, I have a method that ensures the funcion has one only paramether and then calculates the derivative (only as expression):

```
from sympy import *
import inspect
def get_derivative(fun):
    parameters=inspect.getargspec(f).args
    if(len(parameters)>1):
       raise ValueError('Function has more than one parameter.')
    fdiff=fun(Symbol(parameters[0])).diff()
    print(fdiff)
```

Let's say that `fdiff` contains the main expression of derivative function, so, the problem I want to solve is returning a function in order to evaluate it, for example:

```
f_deriv=get_derivative(f1p) #f_deriv is a callable function 
print(f_deriv(a)) #Prints derivative value of f1p in a
```

**Note:** I've try `return eval/exec(diff)` but is a bad idea, because declaring parameters is needed. Also I tried to wrap the expresion with:

```
eval('def foo('+parameters[0]+'):\n\treturn '+diff)
```

And it still is not a good idea.

#### Extending main problem

Suppose now we use (for example) logarithms in our base function, so, we implement it this way

```
import math
def f1p(x):
    return x**2 + 5**x * 2*x + 1 + math.log(x)
```

When I apply the previous function to this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

This is due to Sympy is not capable of understand `math.log(x)`. So, my questions are:

- To solve main problem: Is there any way to return a callable function from `get_derivative` function?
- To solve extended problem: Is there any way to translate sympy expression to Python evaluable expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) to return callable from your `get_derivative`:

```
import inspect
from sympy import symbols, diff
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

def get_derivative(function):
    if len(inspect.getfullargspec(function).args) > 1:
        raise ValueError('Function has more than one parameter.')
    x = symbols('x')
    return lambdify(x, diff(f1p(x), x))
```

Checking result for your first `f1p` version:

```
def f1p(x):
    return x**2 + 5**x * 2*x + 1


derivative = get_derivative(f1p)
derivative(1)
```

This will give `28.094379124341003`. It's a correct result.

---

Now, if you want to use logarithm, then you should use the one from *sympy*, not from *math*:

```
from sympy import log
def f1p(x):
    return x**2 + 5**x * 2*x + 1 + log(x)


derivative = get_derivative(f1p)
derivative(1)
```

This will give `29.094379124341003`. Also correct.

Comment: The response for the main problem is almost what I was looking for. It allowed me to find the correct solution, so thanks for it. For the problem extension, maybe, I exposed a bad example, but it works so far. Thanks at all, Georgy!